# Dynamics GP 10 table name

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

Are the table names for GP 10 the exact same as GP 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is: for the most part, yes. [Here](http://www.box.net/shared/jc90kdsh2k) is the master table reference.

Comment: All these years later, that link just saved me hours

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty good table reference here:
http://dyndeveloper.com/dynModule.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have access to customersource with Microsoft Dynamics GP you can also download the SDK which will give you all the version changes, along with entity relationship maps that you can use as well for troubleshooting any db issues.